# Are LEGO tires natural or synthetic rubber?

Tags: piece-information, plastics, bricks-and-pieces

LEGO is the No.1 tire maker in the world by number of unit. It produce the same number of tires in a year as both Michelin & Bridgestone together, the 2 biggest tire manufacturers.
A "real" vehicle tire is made of a mix of Natural Rubber (coming from a tree: Hevea Brasiliensis) and Synthetic Rubber (coming from oil). Is this the same for the LEGO tire or is it only Synthetic rubber that is used?

Comment: While the other question is not an exact duplicate, the answers cover this question also.

Comment: @chicks Perhaps this is semantic, but a duplicate is pertaining to the question only, not just applicable answers. Answers thus aside, this isn't really a duplicate.

Comment: @chicks Also, the bands aren't made of the same rubber as the tires nowadays, so the answers aren't applicable.

Comment: @CalebWoodman The (your) accepted answer from 5 July this year  states "**Tires** and elastic materials found in some LEGO sets are manufactured from Styrene-Butadiene Styrene (SBS)"?